# How to `cat` filename returned by `which`?

Tags: command-line, bash

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310942/how-do-i-know-what-version-of-gjslint-i-have-installed/6311878#6311878) but realize that it could be better.

How can I convert:

```
$ which gjslint
$ cat /usr/local/bin/gjslint
```

Into something like this:

```
$ cat < which gjslint
-bash: which: No such file or directory
```

..so that the output path+filename from `which` is passed onto `cat` which then does it's thing (i.e. printing the contents of the filename to the screen).

Comment: Funny, your answer on SO has been updated a minute after I posted mine.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but my intent was to learn, improve my answer on SO, and thus asked a question on AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use backticks:

```
cat `which gjslint`
```

If the path contains whitespace (unlikely with default paths), you need to put it in parentheses:

```
cat "`which gjslint`"
```

An alternative would be `cat "$(which gjslint)"`. The reason I use backticks instead of `$()` is because it's easier to type, two keystrokes with one hand vs 4 keystrokes with two hands. I am aware of the disadvantages of using `` ` `` over `$()`, but those do no apply in this case. You're not going to nest backticks or use slashes for quickly finding a program.

Comment: There is [an argument](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) that `$(which gjslint)` is preferable. I can't personally speak for validity of this particular argument, but I do tend to trust the content of the site it was posted on.

Comment: Updated why I use backticks instead of `$()`.

Comment: See [Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126928/85039) The backticks are slightly outdated and mostly for compatibility with older systems.  They're easier to type but they handle backslashes and don't make nesting commands easy.  Also, very easy to misread

Answer (score 0):

What you have in the linked question is:

```
$ cat $(which gjslint) | grep [0-9] --color=always
```

What you can do is:

```
$ grep '[0-9]' --color=always "$(which gjslint)"
```

There's couple points to note:

- no need to `cat` file. `grep` takes files as arguments
- single-quote your regex; the reason for that is because shell will try to expand `[0-9]` as filenames. If there were files 0,1,2,3 and so on to 9, the shell would expand your command to `grep 0 1 2 3 ...` and the rest of args. Try doing this - `touch 0 1 2 && stat [0-2]`, and you'll see. This can become a problem if you need to pass output of `grep` somewhere else